# Transiting the US after overstaying my Canadian student visa

Tags: usa, transit, canada, indian-citizens, overstaying

I have overstayed my Canadian student visa. I have a valid Indian passport and a valid American visa too. I have booked my flight to voluntarily leave the country  and I shall be informing the immigration officers on departure.

I have not received any deportation or departure orders. I realized I was in a soup and decided to leave before it was too late.

My question is, if I declare my departure, will I have trouble at the US airports while transiting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to say but I would imagine the US Immigration will not be interested in your Canadian credentials if you have a valid US visa. Moreover, the fact you overstayed in Canada is not directly a concern to them, although I suppose it establishes evidence that you might overstay in the US. Can anyone else comment on this?

Comment: It's quite possible that the US won't even know. As always, you shouldn't mention it unless specifically asked.

Comment: "and I shall be informing the immigration officers on departure. " Canada does not have "immigration officers on departure".

Comment: Are you transiting in the US or travelling there ? Also, depending on where you are, you might pass US customs at the airport in Canada